# Opencart настройка .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

Для сайта все работает, мне нужно для панели администратора.

Если на странице `site.ru/admin` неправильно ввести логин или пароль, будет переадресация на страницу `site.ru/admin/index.php?route=common/login`.

Как это можно убрать с помощью **.htaccess** или возможно это можно исправить как то в коде? Нужно чтобы при переадресация была на `site.ru/admin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В идеале нужно настраивать ЧПУ для админ панели, но мне с таким не доводилось сталкиваться, как вариант могу предложить дописать в котроллере

```
/admin/controller/common/login.php
```

после строки

```
$data['action'] = $this->url->link('common/login', '', 'SSL');
```

следующее

```
$data['action'] = str_replace("index.php?route=common/login", "", $data['action']);
```

решение конечно костыль, но может помочь если это только для формы такое нужно.

Comment: Да, только для формы, спасибо